# Result of Hadoop MapReduce isn't writing any data to output file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've been trying to debug this error for a while now. Basically, I've confirmed that my reduce class is writing the correct output to its context, but for some reason I'm always getting a zero bytes output file.

My mapper class:

```
public class FrequencyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {


public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Document t = Jsoup.parse(value.toString());
    String text = t.body().text();
    String[] content = text.split(" ");

    for (String s : content) {
        context.write(new Text(s), new IntWritable(1));
    }
}
```

}

My reducer class:

```
public class FrequencyReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int n = 0;
    for (IntWritable i : values) {
        n++;
    }
    if (n > 5) {    // Do we need this check?
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(n));
        System.out.println("<" + key + ", " + n + ">");
    }
}
```

}

and my driver:

```
public class FrequencyMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);

    // setup the job
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "FrequencyCount");
    job.setJarByClass(FrequencyMain.class);

    job.setMapperClass(FrequencyMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(FrequencyReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(FrequencyReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

}

And for some reason "reduce output records" is always

```
Job complete: job_local805637130_0001
Counters: 17
  Map-Reduce Framework
    Spilled Records=250
    Map output materialized bytes=1496
    Reduce input records=125
    Map input records=6
    SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=1000
    Map output bytes=57249
    Reduce shuffle bytes=0
    Reduce input groups=75
    Combine output records=125
    Reduce output records=0
    Map output records=5400
    Combine input records=5400
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=3606577152
  File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=509446
  FileSystemCounters
    FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=385570
    FILE_BYTES_READ=2909134
  File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=8
```

Comment: Reduce Input Records are 125 only. Try running the mapper only, followed by validation of the conditions in the Reducer. It looks like the filter condition is not being fulfilled...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming that your goal is to print word frequencies which have frequencies > 5)

Current implementation of combiner totally breaks semantics of your program. You need either to remove it or reimplement:

1. Currently it passes only those words to reducer which have frequencies of at least 5. Combiner works per-mapper, this means, for example, if only single document is scheduled into some mapper, then this mapper/combiner won't emit words which have frequencies in this document less than 6 (even if other documents in other mappers have lots of occurencies of these words). You need to remove check `n > 5` in combiner (but not in reducer).
2. Because now reducer input values are not neccessarily all "ones", you should increment `n` by value amount instead of `n++`.

Comment: Removing the line `job.setCombinerClass(FrequencyReducer.class);` in my driver class fixed the problem, thanks!